# PathLocationStrategy returning 404 in Angular 12

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404, angular12

The application is returning 404 when hit in browser.
`<base href="/app/">`

Above is the index.html reference.

app.module has

`{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}`

url accessed is **http://localhost:8080/app/graphdb-services/**

Also the code is working fine with *HashLocationStrategy*

But due to requirements , I need to avoid # in the URL.

Also app.module.ts has,

`RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)`

I tried the option of `APP_BASE_HREF` but no luck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The objective is solved for Tomcat, need simliar solve for jetty

Comment: http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/?unapproved=4436&moderation-hash=fba0216cc1cb22f2c0233872a06bc64d